# PHP SQL injection and protection?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection)

This is my attempt at cleaning up what I will be putting into my database

```
$pictureID = $_REQUEST['pictureID'];
$userID = $_REQUEST['userID'];
$username = $_REQUEST['username'];

//Sanatize //Protext against injection

$username = filter_var($username, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$userID = filter_var($userID, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$pictureID = filter_var($pictureID, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

$username = stripslashes($username);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);

$userID = stripslashes($userID);
$userID = mysql_real_escape_string($userID);

$pictureID = stripslashes($pictureID);
$pictureID = mysql_real_escape_string($pictureID);
```

I have two questions, is the above enough?

Also, if I do `echo $pictureID` nothing appears, however, if I remove the `$pictureID = mysql_real_escape_string($pictureID);` then `echo $pictureID` works.

Is this the correct behavior?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: ...possible duplicate? lol ...thinking maybe SO needs an auto reply for mysql_ / PDO questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow...

You really **do not** need that much.

Try using PDO or mysqli with a prepared query, then all of that nonsense should not be needed.

---

See this canned comment for advice:

> [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 1):

To **protect against SQL-injection**, the only required call is this:

```
  $pictureID = mysql_real_escape_string( $pictureID );
```

This method-call **effectively escapes all special characters**, which could potentially change the intended operation of your query.

As @NullPointer pointed out, using [PHP's PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) would be a **good alternative**, since mysql_* is deprecated as of PHP 5.5+. Nevertheless, I don't think it will get completely removed from PHP very soon.

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string doesn`t prevent sql attacks
See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814642/can-mysql-real-escape-string-alone-prevent-all-kinds-of-sql-injection.

If you read through you will find out there are number of ways to fool mysql_real_escape_string or mysqli_real_escape_string